# Determine whether to use DB.Exec or DB.Query from unknown query string

Tags: sql, database, go

Using "`database/sql`", `sql.DB.Exec()` is used for queries that do not return rows (`insert, delete, update`) and `sql.DB.Query(`) for queries that return rows (`selects`).
Assume you have an incoming query string which you wish to execute, however you do not know whether the query intends to return rows.
Can you think of a way to find out whether to use Exec or Query?

Comment: Not knowing your sql statement before running it sounds like a security nightmare. Other than that, if you really, REALLY trust the sql, you can probably just run everything with Query and accept that sometimes the query won't return a result set. It's not perfect (e.g. you won't know how many records were modified by UPDATE queries) but the only other safe solution I can think of would be to rearchitect something upstream.

Comment: security is not an issue, assume that you are writing a wrapper function, unfortunately, using Query() for all query strings will not work for many C_UD operations.

Comment: I'd throw in that the incident which is inevitably going to happen does not necessarily have to come from malicious intent. However, as far as I get the sql package, it is merely a question wether something is returned or not. So basically, you can use query all the time, it might just happen that `*Rows` is nil or empty. A simple guard should do the trick.

Comment: create, update, delete or insert operations using Query() will not return an error and Rows will not be nil but the query will not succeed. 
GORM (the db orm) for example has two functions Exec and Row which in the background are used for sql.DB.Exec() and sql.DB.Query() respectively

Answer (score 3):

In any cases, don't try to parse SQL since it's hacky. Just use `Query` if you are not sure, `Query` should be able to handle C_UD well and return an empty result set in that case. Both `Query` and `Exec` should have exactly the same effect, and they only differ in their response. Only use `Exec` if the user of your API explicitly does not need the results.

Comment: I'm  100% agree with advice "don't try to parse SQL"  but I would use stronger words than just "hacky".  More proper: "impossible in general case to predict by parsing `query string` parameter existence/non-existence of output".

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not that simple as it may seem from the first sight.

Let's clarify the problem:

Question is not about particular database as pgsql/mysql/sqlite/other but for any generic database drive.

So the answer must be in  `database/sql/driver`.

Let's go further:

`sql/driver`. Interfaces: `Queryer`/`QueryerContext` & `Execer`/`ExecerContext`

Module `sql/driver` defines interfaces:

- `Queryer`/`QueryerContext` - for ability to `(*DB).Query`
- `Execer`/`ExecerContext` - for `(*DB).Exec`
- others such as `Pinger`

Note that **every interface** described in documentation as *" an optional interface that may be implemented by a Conn"*

Which means that it's possible to implement sql driver without `Query` and/or `Exec`.

**Experimental verification**

Let's try to implement **correct** database driver that cannot `Query` and `Exec`: https://play.golang.org/p/sZiigEghphE

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "database/sql/driver"
    "log"
)

type expdrv struct{}
type expconn struct{}

// sql.Driver implementation
func (*expdrv) Open(name string) (driver.Conn, error) {
    return &expconn{}, nil
}

// driver.Conn implementation
func (c *expconn) Prepare(query string) (driver.Stmt, error) {
    return nil, nil
}

func (c *expconn) Close() error {
    return nil
}

func (c *expconn) Begin() (driver.Tx, error) {
    return nil, nil
}

func main() {
    sql.Register("drvexp", &expdrv{})
    log.Printf("Registred drivers: %v\n", sql.Drivers())

    db, err := sql.Open("drvexp", "")
    log.Printf("sql.Open() success: %v, error: %v", db != nil, err)

    log.Println("db.Close() error:", db.Close())
}
```

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Registred drivers: [drvexp]
2009/11/10 23:00:00 sql.Open() success: true, error: 
2009/11/10 23:00:00 db.Ping()  success: true
2009/11/10 23:00:00 db.Close() success: true
2009/11/10 23:00:00 db.Ping()  result:  sql: database is closed
```

It works!

This `Driver` implementation is:

- correct from `database/sql` standpoint
- has no working methods `Query` and `Exec` (attempt will throw panic)
- surprisingly working `Ping()`

**Possibility to implement `Exec` or `Query` independently of each other**

Let's add `Exec`:

```golang
// driver.Result & driver.Execer
type expresult struct{}

func (*expconn) Exec(query string, args []driver.Value) (driver.Result, error) {
    return &expresult{}, nil
}

func (*expresult) LastInsertId() (int64, error) {
    return 0, nil
}

func (*expresult) RowsAffected() (int64, error) {
    return 0, nil
}
```

will allow:

```golang
_, err = db.Exec("BYE")
fmt.Println("db.Exec() success:", err == nil) // Outputs: true
```

**Conclusion**

- Ability to call `Query/QueryContext` and/or `Exec/ExecContext` are optional
- Behaviour of those methods can vary at great length between drivers
- In general case there is no correct answer exists
- For particular cases (with specific driver):

  - it's possible to suppose that `db.Query` would work for most cases
  - but it's impossible to guarantee that `Query` will really work without experimental verification

Thank you for your attention!

I suppose that's the final answer.